# File name with prefix and number

Tags: c#, filenames

i have this problem, I want create this filename of xml file:

```
NOHEL+number.xml
```

The number is from variable number, where i added +1 always when i send file out. NOHEL is prefix.
Exapmle:

```
NOHEL1.xml
NOHEL2.xml
NOHEL3.xml
```

And i want give there...

```
string strFileName = @"C:\\Users\\L\\Desktop\\NOHEL+number.xml";
```

Have you any ideas?

Comment: `string strFileName = @"C:\Users\L\Desktop\NOHEL" + number + ".xml";`, and you don't need to escape characters with `\ ` when you have `@`.

Comment: @Trickery, that should be an answer

Comment: Or  `string strFileName = string.Format(@"C:\Users\L\Desktop\NOHEL{0}.xml", number);`

Comment: String concatenating are the most basics of every programming language. The question is just to trivial.

Comment: @Tarec That's what I figured. But what the hell, might as well post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks :)  string strFileName = string.Format(@"C:\Users\L\Desktop\NOHEL{0}.xml", number);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
string strFileName = @"C:\Users\L\Desktop\NOHEL" + number + ".xml";
```

By the way, you don't need to escape characters with `\` when you have `@`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
string.Format(@"C:\Users\L\Desktop\NOHEL{0}.xml", number)
```

or

```
@"C:\Users\L\Desktop\NOHEL" + number + ".xml".
```

And there is no need to make double slash when you use @ symbol.